# How to remove html part of a text in PHP

Tags: php, html, string

I have a question about parsing text and removing unwanted html parts.
I know functions like - strip_tags() which will remove all the tags, but the problem is, that this function leaves the "inside text" there.

Let me show you an example, we have a text:

```
Hello, how are you? <a href="">Link to my website</a> __Here continues html tags, links, images__
```

What I want is to remove the whole part, where html resides. Not only tags, but also text (like "Link to my website" above).

Is there any efficient way, function that I missed?

Comment: Are you sure this is what you really want to do? If you stripped the text within the tags you would also risk removing content that was bolded or italicized, or worse.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't stress that the text before(!) the html part is just plain text. No tags inside that part. So this procedure will not affect any text that should be displayed afterwards

Comment: There's a function in the manual comments on strip_tags() that promises to do what you want: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php#97386 I'm not aware of an easier solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
function removeTags($str) {
    $result = '';

    $xpath = new DOMXPath(DOMDocument::loadHTML(sprintf('<body>%s</body>', $str)));
    foreach ($xpath->query('//body/text()') as $textNode) {
        $result .= $textNode->nodeValue;
    }

    return $result;
}

echo removeTags(
    'Hello, how are you? <a href="">Link to my website</a> __Here continues html <span>tags</span>, links, images__'
);
```

Output:

```
Hello, how are you? __Here continues html , links, images__
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not make it a rule that the submittet input are not allowed to contain tags.

```
function containsIllegalHtml($input, $allowable_tags = '') {
    if($input != strip_tags($input, $allowable_tags)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Use this function to check wether the input contains tags or not.

Comment: Unfortunatly I have no control over the text. I receive it and parse is in the moment when I can do nothing about it. But if I could, this would be good solution.

Answer (score 1):

maybe its not correct, but...

```
$str = 'Hello, how are you? <a href="">Link to my website</a> __Here continues html tags, links, ';
$rez = preg_replace("/\<.*\>/i",'',$str);
var_dump($rez);
```

gave me an output

```
string 'Hello, how are you?  __Here continues html tags, links, ' (length=56)
```

Comment: I think your RegEx is a bit "greedy". What is the output if you use `$str = 'Hello, how are you? <a href="">Link to my website</a> keep this <b>remove this</b> __Here continues html tags, links, ';`

Comment: `var_dump` tells me `string 'Hello, how are you?  __Here continues html tags, links, ' (length=56)` so, yes, its greedy :)

Answer (score 0):

you may write a function that takes a string 
and it uses php string capabilities to get the position of the "<" and then the position of the ">" and strip them from the input string

Comment: Yes, probably this will be the only way to do it. I have just wondered, if there is a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

i have searched and found this solution

```
$txt = "
<html>
<head><title>Something wicked this way comes</title></head>
<body>
This is the interesting stuff I want to extract
</body>
</html>";

$text = preg_replace("/<([^<>]*)>/", "", $txt);

echo htmlentities($text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Some preg magic?

```
$text = preg_replace('/<[\/\!]*?[^<>]*?>/si', '', $text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will work:

http://htmlpurifier.org/

Here is tutorial

http://www.zendcasts.com/writing-custom-zend-filters-with-htmlpurifier/2011/06/

it's for Zend Framework but I think it may helps