# Regular expression from wysiwyg

Tags: php, expression

I have HTML-code, that come from user who use wysiwyg redactor.

I need to сlean code from tags like `<b ..><i ..><strong><p><a ..>`, and clean up from all main js code, like onclick and other.

Thanks.

Comment: So you want to convert the html to plain text?

Comment: Yes, and then i need to check for closing tags in right way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use strip_tags to remove html from text. Example below.

```
$text = '<p>Test paragraph.</p><!-- Comment --> <a href="#fragment">Other text</a>';
echo strip_tags($text);
echo "\n";
```

Comment: check this link also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6531194/how-to-remove-html-part-of-a-text-in-php

Comment: try this if your js is inside script tags: echo preg_replace('/<script\b[^>]*>(.*?)<\/script>/is', "", $var);